# Access to the register

Tags: c, embedded, vivado

I'm using the soft-core Cortex-M0, Keil uvision 5, vivado 14.4 I interfaced an accelerator with my ARM architecture,

When I do this, everything was alright in the Vivado simulator

```
volatile signed int *rega = (volatile signed int *) 0x59000000; 

*rega = 45;
```

but when I try this

```
volatile signed int *rega = (volatile signed int *) 0x59000000; 

int A[] = {45,45};
*rega = A[0];
```

the simulation doesn't work, there's no access to the register:`0x59000000`

Comment: Are you sure that first case works well. Or are you sure that the second one doesn't work?...

Comment: yes i'm sure, in the first case, when HADDR=0x59000000 HWDATA= 45 but in the second case,HADDR=05900000 but HWDARA=X

Comment: Do you have the (dis)assembly for those sections?

Comment: @maria :  The information you just placed in a comment regarding what actually *happens* belongs in the question - edit it.  All diagnostic information available to you belongs in the question - otherwise you'll just get questions about your question as people try to get the information available to you and necessary to answer the question. "[it] doesn'tt work" is insufficient information.

Comment: There is too little information to reproduce the problem, although it sounds like a tool bug. And what has Verilog to do with this?